# can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

При попытке развертывания django приложения на heroku `heroku run python manage.py migrate` пишет ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дерево проекта[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static","static_dev"),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_prod")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "media")
```

Comment: Может вы не спушили?
git push heroku master

Comment: Спушил, но тоже были проблемы, нужно было создавать еще одну ветку, master выдавал ошибку

Comment: @playrus  а как именно спушить? какой командой? это решило проблему? у меня та же самая ошибка https://clck.ru/QTavr